# Assigning results for a FOR XML EXPLICIT UNION to a variable

Tags: sql-server-2008, for-xml-explicit

This query works fine

```
SELECT 1 AS TAG, NULL AS parent, 1 [dog!1]
UNION (SELECT 1,NULL, 3) 
FOR XML EXPLICIT, ROOT('dogs')
```

I would like to assign it to a variable. This works fine without the union:

```
DECLARE @x xml
SET @x = ((
  (SELECT 1 AS TAG, NULL AS parent, 1 [dog!1]
   FOR XML EXPLICIT, ROOT('dogs'))
  ))
```

As soon as I introduce the union it doesn't work:

```
DECLARE @x xml
SET @x = ((
  (SELECT 1 AS TAG, NULL AS parent, 1 [dog!1]
   UNION (SELECT 1,NULL, 3) 
   FOR XML EXPLICIT, ROOT('dogs'))
   ))
```

Tried all sorts of things. What am I missing

Comment: What error are you geting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add one more sub-query level like this:

```
DECLARE @X XML = 
(
  SELECT * FROM
  (
    SELECT 1 AS TAG, NULL AS parent, 1 [dog!1]
    UNION 
    SELECT 1,NULL, 3
  )X
  FOR XML EXPLICIT, ROOT('dogs')
);

SELECT @X;
```

Comment: Just wanted to chime in that this isn't working in my scenario.  I am using CDATA (`[dog!1!ColumnAlias!cdata]`), and yet the CDATA is not being included in the XML output.  Running the contents of the outer parentheses does include the CDATA tags; I need to get that exact output into an XML variable.